# A problem with texture changes when joining meshes

Tags: mesh, uv, shaders

I have a "wing" model that is made to look like it is made from palm fronds rather than feathers, so the color texture is designed for that - each leaf on a frond has a shaded color (using a color ramp) to give it a leaf-like look. The outer parts to which they are joined are a simple green vine color. When I join them, I lose the subtle shading on the leaf meshes. I have given them all the same UV name, but the shading is still lost when I join them. I'm not sure why, and it's frustrating. [image: Palm Frond Wing Separated]
Here it is joined:
[image: Palm Frond Wing Joined]
And the texture node setup for the shaded color:
[image: Texture Node Setup]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file before joining? don't forget to pack the images https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the two wings have been shaded in different ways? I know that if you join a Smooth Shaded object with a differently shaded object it can become messed up, but except for that I really don't know.